# WooCommerce - Don't display cross sells products which are out of the stock on cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

My theme displays cross sell products on cart page which is fine.

This is done via the code below which can be found in the `cart/cross-sells.php` template file.

```php
<?php foreach ( $cross_sells as $cross_sell ) : ?>

    <?php
        $post_object = get_post( $cross_sell->get_id() );

        setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited, Squiz.PHP.DisallowMultipleAssignments.Found

        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

---

But I dont want to display products which are out of the stock

I managed to change number of columns for cross sells etc but i cant find anywhere some snippet that displays only available products.

Can someone walk me through how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

woocommerce->settings->productst->inventory->out of stock visibility = check this button.

Comment: Will that affect my catalog and other pages as well?

Answer (score 2):

There are always multiple solutions but 1 of them could be by overwriting the template file

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.8.0/templates/cart/cross-sells.php

**Replace (line: 28 - 38)**

```php
<?php foreach ( $cross_sells as $cross_sell ) : ?>

    <?php
        $post_object = get_post( $cross_sell->get_id() );

        setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.OverrideProhibited, Squiz.PHP.DisallowMultipleAssignments.Found

        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**With**

```php
<?php foreach ( $cross_sells as $cross_sell ) : ?>

    <?php
        $stock_status = $cross_sell->get_stock_status();

        if ( $stock_status != 'outofstock' ) {

            $post_object = get_post( $cross_sell->get_id() );

            setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.OverrideProhibited, Squiz.PHP.DisallowMultipleAssignments.Found

            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        }
    ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @7uc1f3r's answer, I came up with this solution that also hides the title in the cas there's no product to display.

I did override `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cross-sells.php`, creating a file in my child theme `/wp-content/themes/MY-CHILD-THEME/woocommerce/content-product.php`, with the following code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Cross-sells
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cross-sells.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 4.4.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

if ( $cross_sells ) : ?>
    <?php
        ob_start();
        foreach ( $cross_sells as $cross_sell ) :
            $stock_status = $cross_sell->get_stock_status();
            if ( $stock_status != 'outofstock' ) { // only display product if it is not out of stock
                $post_object = get_post( $cross_sell->get_id() );

                setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited, Squiz.PHP.DisallowMultipleAssignments.Found

                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
            }
        endforeach;
        $html = ob_get_clean();
        if ($html) { // only display the whole cross sells section of there's something to display
            ?>
                <div class="cross-sells">
                    <?php
                    $heading = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_cross_sells_products_heading', __( 'You may be interested in&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ) );

                    if ( $heading ) :
                        ?>
                        <h2><?php echo esc_html( $heading ); ?></h2>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                    <?php echo $html; ?>

                    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

                </div>

            <?php
        }
    ?>
    <?php
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```